# Get current line of contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable

I've poked around and read that there is no method to find the current line in a `div contenteditable` so I'm trying to write a script to best estimate the current line.

```
var curLine = 1;
var curColumn = 1;

$(".editable").onkeydown = function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    switch( keyCode ) {
        case 13:
            console.log("Enter; on line: " + curLine);
            curLine++;
            break;

        case 8:
            if( /* current line has a text length of 0 */ ) {
                console.log("Previous line prepended; previous enter reversed; on line: " + curLine);
                do {
                    curLine--;
                } while( curLine > 0 );
            }
            // } else if( /* single digit removed */ ) {
                // console.log("Bit prepended");
            // }
            break;
    }
};
```

So, as you can see, I have a few questions. This bit: `if( /* current line has a text length of 0 */ )` I can't seem to be able to target the current line and see if its string length is 0. Also, my `do...while` statement doesn't work, as if I hit backspace on the first line over and over again, it goes into negative numbers (when it should just stay at 1 [`> 0`]). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me in Chrome. Will test in other browsers now:

```
$(".editable").on("keyup", function(keyCode){
    var linesCount = $(".editable div").length + 1;
    $("#linesCount").html(linesCount + " lines.");
    return linesCount;
});
```

For every line, the content editable div will create a new div child. If you count these divs, you get the total amount of lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/PypeD/

Edit: For FF this actually produces `<br>` tags. You could count those.

FF: http://jsfiddle.net/PypeD/1/

Comment: Thanks! One thing I realized though, is if the user has say, 5 lines, and then clicks onto line 3, there's no way to tell until the user starts typing. But I guess that's all that matters. Thanks again!

Comment: Clean and succinct. I love it. Unfortunately, the FF method doesn't work if you paste in text from another source. Going to try the Chrome version on multiple browsers and see how it works now.

Comment: ...is there a reason why you wouldn't count `\n`..?

Comment: @TimBiden, yes this works on `keyup` only and this doesn't answer how to get **current** line number